# Coding programming error using ActionScript

Tags: actionscript

I am wondering if anyone can help resolve my problem. I am using the NetConnection and NetStream classes to connect to a webcam feed using Flash Media Server. However, this appears every time in my output:

ArgumentError: Error #2126: NetConnection object must be connected. at flash.net::NetStream/ctor() at flash.net::NetStream()

I have tweaked around with the code but to no avail.

Any ideas as to why this isn't working? Here is the (I think relevant) code:

```
 import flash.net.NetConnection;
 import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
 import flash.net.NetStream;
 import flash.events.AsyncErrorEvent;

 var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();

 nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netHandler);

 nc.connect("rtmfp://localhost//myUrlExample");

var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);

 ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netHandler);
 ns.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, asyncErrorHandler);

 ns.publish("myStream", "recording");

function netHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void{
    switch(event.info.code){
        case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
         trace("Successs");
        break;

        case "NetConnection.Connect.Failed":
         trace("Cannot connect to the server");
         break;

         case "NetConnection.Connect.Rejected":
         trace("Ouch!");
        break;
    }
}

function asyncErrorHandler(event:AsyncErrorEvent):void{
        //ignore error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are creating and initializing both  NetStream and NetConection before conductor call.  Did you try putting that code inside constructor or any other function?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to wait for the `NetConnection` to actually connect to the server before you try to `publish()` the `NetStream`.

You know when the connection has been established from the `NetStatusEvent` that you're already listening to. So inside the `switch` statement where the connection attempt succeeds, is when you should wire up the `NetStream` and publish it:

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netHandler); 
nc.connect("rtmfp://localhost//myUrlExample");

var ns:NetStream;

function netHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void{
    switch(event.info.code){
        case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
            trace("Successs");
            ns = new NetStream(nc);
            ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netHandler);
            ns.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, asyncErrorHandler);
            ns.publish("myStream", "recording");
        break;

        case "NetConnection.Connect.Failed":
            trace("Cannot connect to the server");
            break;

        case "NetConnection.Connect.Rejected":
            trace("Ouch!");
            break;
    }
}
```